# Can data from a db be displayed on a web page?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a very simple question: when loading a web page the `Page_Load` function is called so that the page can be loaded. In this function can I insert some code that allows me to select and view in the browser the data present in an external database?

Comment: Hello! We're going to need a lot more information before we can help. You will need "backend" technology running on the server to access your SQL database, such as node (if you're using javascript). In turn your webpage will need to contact the server to do that. I recommend looking for a tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807895/5764432) answer could be of help.

You could then write a script that fetches data from a database. How you do that is a question in it self but I can recommend checking out [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) which is good for learning plain Javascript in the beginning.

Comment: yes i guess i will take a look there, thank you very much